# Download web page through google chrome/chromium in linux terminal

Tags: html, linux, google-chrome, terminal, chromium

Is there a way that gives me the opportunity to download html webpages through google chrome or chromium using only commands in the terminal. 
WGET doesn't seem to work well for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [httrack](http://www.httrack.com/page/2/uk/).

> It allows you to download a World Wide Web site from the Internet to a local directory, building recursively all directories, getting HTML, images, and other files from the server to your computer.

Comment: does it take javascript files too

Comment: It's seems yes : `Links options:
 %P *extended parsing, attempt to parse all links, even in unknown tags or Javascript (%P0 don't use) (--extended-parsing[=N])
  n  get non-html files 'near' an html file (ex: an image located outside) (--near)` There are so many options. Just read the doc and look at the examples. [httrack](https://www.httrack.com/html/fcguide.html)